# Sending GET/POST requests to Google APIs from Django

Tags: django, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have a Django 1.10 project from which I have to make GET/POST requests to [Google APIs](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?pli=1&project=android-blend-159717).

I have succeeded to pass Google OAuth 2.0 authorization process in the following code:

```
def a_oauth2(request):

    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json',
                                           scope=...,
                                           redirect_uri=)
    flow.params['access_type'] = 'offline'         # offline access
    flow.params['include_granted_scopes'] = 'true'   # incremental auth

    if 'code' not in request.GET:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = request.GET['code']
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

And here's where I am stuck. My goal now is to export Google Drive document. The question is, how do I retrieve the OAuth token and pass it to the [respective GET request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)? And how does the `discovery.build(...)` method fit into the story?